# New to calisthenics and would like some help

Tags: bodyweight-exercises, beginners

Background: 15 y/o, 70kg, 184cm. New to working out, only been doing for 3 months. Would like to ask if this workout is optimal and is there anything to improve? I do see good progress in strength but I would like to see if there's anything I can do to for example reach these goals.

I'll be answering all the questions you guys have and would like to learn something new. Also I'm only sticking to calisthenics as I favor it more then bodybuilding.

Important: don't have any dip bars, resistance bands etc. no equipment expect for a pullup bar outside.

1 chinup/pullup
25 pushups

Rest time: 2-3min

First day

10 of 3 sets regular pushups (if cannot finish goto knee pushups for the last remaining reps),
12 of 3 sets roman twists,
12 of 3 sets knee raises,
12 of 3 sets squats,
12 of 3 sets lunges,
12 of 3 sets calf raises,
x of low plank,

Second day

x of 1 set knee pushups,
x of 1 set diamond knee pushups,
x of 1 set normal pushups,
x of 3 sets crunches,
15 of 3 sets knee raises,
12-15 of 3 sets roman twists,
12 of 3 sets calf raises,
12 of 3 sets squats,
12 of 3 sets lunges,
x of decline low plank,

Third day

x of 1 set clapping kneepushups,
x of 1 set normal pushups,
12 of 3 sets crunches,
12 of 3 sets knee raises,
12 of 3 sets roman twists,
12 of 3 sets calf raises,
12 of 3 sets squats,
12 of 3 sets lunges,
x of low plank

Comment: You don't have a pulling exercise in your routine, I would recommend you add pull ups, or if you can't do them try bodyweight rows.

Comment: Well if you read, I am a beginner and pullups or anything similiar is practicly impossible for me.

Comment: Have you tried bodyweight rows?

Comment: Just to follow on from Paradox's comment, one of the easiest ways to do this at home is to use your kitchen table, putting your feet under it, grabbing the edge, and pulling up. Initially, you can even bend your knees and put your feet flat on the ground to make it easier. Another similar "do it at home" exercise is to stand with your feet straddling an open door, grabbing the doorknob on both sides, leaning out, and doing pulls up into the doorknob and back.

Comment: "Negative" pullups (i.e., jump up, lower down slowly) is another option, and chinups can help w/ biceps. Roman twists are always suspect w/o a form check. Some equipment can be home-brewed--search for "hojo undo" for a Japanese approach. Never underestimate a sack of heavy.

Comment: Thank you alot Sean, I'll be sure to add that to my workout and try that today. Thank you alot for the help!

Comment: Yeah I understand and that's what I am going forward right now, the problem is my lack of strength in the core or whatever that requires to do the pullups. Yes the pushups I already worked from and in just 2 months I went from 0 to 12 by doing them elevated. But with pullups it's impossible for me to do 1, I tried to walk around but can't find anywhere where I can do australian pullups. The only thing I can do is probably knee raises on the pullup bar or just hanging if that's enough to improve my "pullup" strength. I also do planks and stuff which should help with the core to get me the stren

Comment: @Outcalled Hanging won't improve your pullup strength because you're not pulling up. Pullups are primarily lats. If you have a place to do pullups you have a place to do negative pullups ("letdowns"?!)

Comment: Yeah but the problem is that my grip strength is pretty poor and I can only be on the pullup bar for around 30 seconds, but yeah I will try doing some negative pullups after my shoulder gets fixed.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, you should be doing just push ups, squats and pull ups every day. Simple, and body weight version.

Do it for 4-5 days a week. Do the maximum possible in about 3 sets. Later on you can try clapping push ups and other exercises.

Also, I think elevated push ups are better than knee push ups. By elevated I mean placing your hands on an elevated platform. If you do any less than 10 of flat push ups in a set, do a set of elevated push ups. Try to reduce the elevation or increase the reps every consecutive day.

I am not of the opinion that you should add anything extra. I think you should do these three exercises till you can do at least 50 push ups and squat and 20 pull ups in the first set. A total of 100, 100, 40 in three sets respectively should be a good number when you can start doing the other exercises.